# Pasar una variable de un componente a otro en vuejs

Tags: vue.js

tengo una duda, estoy intentando pasar una variable de un componente a otro, todo parece funcionar bien, pero dentro del evento del padre no me ejecuta un método.

No logro ver que estoy omitiendo y si pudieran ayudarme. Adjunto algunas imágenes para que puedan ver como si se actualiza mi variable.

Así inicia mi component como pueden ver la variable folder está vacía.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<input-folder v-model="folder" :source.sync="folder" :input-field="false" class="" />
```

Y mi otro componente es el InputFolder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues selecciono el folder como muestra en la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como pueden observar después de darle seleccionar obtengo la ruta del directorio y lleno mi variable folder. Aquí es en el componente inputFolder
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí podemos observar como si me pasa la variable a mi componente padre
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual hago lo siguiente en el inputFolder:

```
methods: {
    select() {
      this.folder = decodeURI(this.$refs.finder.getSelected()[0]);
      this.$emit('input', this.folder);
      this.$emit('folder:selected', this.folder);
      this.$refs.finder.removeSelection();
      this.$refs.modal.close();
    },
 },

watch: {
  folder(folder) {
    this.$emit('input', folder);
  },
},
```

Y en mi otro componente

```
mounted() {
    this.$on('folder:selected', function(folder) {
       this.loadFolder(folder);
    });
},
```

Necesito que me ejecute el this.loadFolder ya que ahí llamo a una función en php y bueno obtengo las imágenes. Muchas gracias por leer esta duda, alguien podría orientarme por donde tengo el error? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero remueve esto de tu metodo `select`:

```
this.$emit('input', this.folder);
```

El `watch` se encarga de hacerlo ya que en la linea anterior le asignas valor a `folder`.

Segundo comentarea el `this.$on` del `mounted e intenta hacerlo a travez de html.

En tu código html del componente donde creas el `input-folder`:

```
<input-folder v-model="folder" :source.sync="folder" :input-field="false" class="" v-on:folder-selected="loadFolder" />
```

Y en el lugar donde emitias `this.$emit('folder:selected'` cambialo por `this.$emit('folderSelected'`

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, funcionó, removí el this.$emit de mi método select, pero en lugar de poner this.$emit('folderSelected, folder)' lo coloqué como this.$emit('folder-selected', folder), como en el v-on del html. Pero ya funcionó. Una pregunta, porque no detectaba en mi mounted? gracias.

Comment: echale un vistazo a este comentario tal vez pueda ayudarte https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/849#issuecomment-307016399